# AWS Kinesis Tumbling-Sliding Window Count (popular/trending count)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm using [AWS Kinesis Data Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/) to try and grab the most popular items coming through my stream. I'd like to be able to see what were the most popular items for the past hour, and have this count updated every minute. In other words, a one-hour sliding window that's updated every minute.

I've almost, but not quite got this working. It does give me a one-hour sliding window that's updated every minute, *for items that have happened to be included in the most recent minute*.

I'd like to have any item that's been seen in the last hour spit out with its count every minute, until its most recent event falls out of the window.

What I've tried:

- First, creating a intermediate [tumbling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/tumbling-window-concepts.html) stream, `TUMBLE_STREAM`, and inserting the count for each `item_id` into this stream at one minute intervals.
- Second, querying the contents of the `TUMBLE_STREAM` over a one hour [sliding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/sliding-window-concepts.html) window and inserting the results into my destination stream.

Here's my SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" ("count" bigint, "item_id" bigint);

CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "TUMBLE_STREAM" ("item_id_count" bigint, "item_id" bigint);

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "TUMBLE_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "TUMBLE_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM COUNT(*) AS item_id_count, "item_id"
FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
GROUP BY FLOOR("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME TO MINUTE), "item_id";

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "SLIDE_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
SELECT STREAM SUM("item_id_count") OVER ONE_HOUR AS "hour_count", "item_id"
FROM "TUMBLE_STREAM"
WINDOW ONE_HOUR AS (
    PARTITION BY "item_id" 
    RANGE INTERVAL '1' HOUR PRECEDING)
ORDER BY "ROWTIME", "hour_count" DESC;
```

This produces output similar to this:

```
ROWTIME                 count item_id
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 1     1
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 1     2
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 2     3
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 10    4
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 26    5
 * one minute later *
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 4     3
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 1     6
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 11    4
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 3     7
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 30    5
```

What I'd like to have is an output more like this:

```
ROWTIME                 count item_id
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 1     1
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 1     2
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 2     3
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 10    4
2018-05-10 17:41:00.001 26    5
 * one minute later *
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 1     1
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 1     2
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 4     3
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 1     6
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 11    4
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 3     7
2018-05-10 17:42:00.001 30    5
```

New `item_id`s can appear in the stream at any time. How can I include all `item_id`s from the past hour in my sliding query's output?